# Error while processing file with AWK

Tags: awk

I have a file that follows this pattern:

```
@ERR202858.267 267 length=100
CGGCCATGCGCGCGGTAGCATATGCATCCTTGCCCTGTTGTTA
+ERR202858.267 267 length=100
BDE@EBFFEFD9DCCGGDE7FBCFF>A5D?758@:BE?BF??<
@ERR202858.268 268 length=100
ATAGGCTCCACGCCTGGTGGTGCCCTTCCGTCAATTCCTTTAAGTT
+ERR202858.268 268 length=100
FFEFEFFFFB@>=D9B>7AB>C4C>@C@?BD??6A=;+,@B@3@@>
```

I have another script that process this file:

```
awk -v header=$header '{if($0~header){if(i>0){printf "\n"$0}else{printf $0}}else{printf "\t"$0};i++}END{printf "\n"}' $1 > $basename1"_tab.tab"
```

Variable "$header" should be `@ERR202858.`

However, I obtain this error for one file:

```
...
@ERR202858.271 271 length=100   GAACTCTTCCCAGGGCCGATGCCGATGTCTCCGGGCTCGCTTGCGTTACCGCC   +ERR202858.271 271 length=100   HHHHHHHHHHGDHHHHHHHHH@GHHHGGHHF@GG/C@@B?DE@FFEB@F=C><
@ERR202858.273 273 length=100   GGCCTCCCCCCGGACCAGCAGCGCCTGATCTTCGCCGGCAAGC +ERR202858.273 273 length=100   EEE/EDC9CACEB8EFBFFFF@FFFDEEFBFFBEFFF@EEDDD
@ERR202858.274 274 length=100   CAACAACATCGGCGGCAACTGGCGCGACGTGCTGTGCAAC    +ERR202858.274 274 length=100   FFFFFFFFFFDFF@BD<D:A?C:A@B>1D?8<><@EEAB@
@ERR202858.275 275 length=100   CTCAGGTGCCCGGCGCGGGGCCAGGAGGGCCAGCTCTTCAGCAAGGTCTGGAA   +ERR202858.275 275 length=100awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=ERR202858_1.trimmed.fq.fastq FNR=884) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
    `   GGGFGFBGGDEGFEF3@B?;4D?ED79%*&???@AECBFFEC@C.C??;:B?='
                                 ^ ran out for this one
```

And this error for another file:

```
@ERR202858.5 5 length=100   CGTGGGGGTATGCCATGGGTATTGCAGGGTAGGCCGATTCGAACCGCGGGTTTTTGTGTTTCCATGCACGGACCTCAGCATTAAAC  +   DIAFGE2E@EFEF@D@A6/>=5>><C=D+B588.8;..;:11-71B=@+30-0675*7**0357-)))).<5..:.2,-79-532>
@ERR202858.6 6 length=100   CCATTGGCGGTGGCGACGATGCCTTTAACAACTTCTTCTCGGAGACCGGCTCCGGGAA  +   @B==@8;C88-257>69..>8:737(61>6)-8@.>-<<<()00'8-,9-)'(87)3?
@ERR202858.7 7 length=100   CGGTGGCGGTCTTGATGATCTGGATGGACGAGGGGCGCACGCGGCGGCGCGCGGCCATCTCCTGGTGGCTCGGGTGGACGTGAGCTGT    +awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=ERR202858_2.trimmed.fq.fastq FNR=24) fatal: no `$' supplied for positional field width or precision
```

Why is this? The script used to work in other files like that one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a format string for `printf`. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html#Basic-Printf

Like `printf "%s", "\n"$0`.